# NFSv4 ACL is not applying despite having matching GIDs on server and client

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, acl

I have a fileserver with nfs exports on it. On the server, I have a `media` directory that I ran `setfacl -m g:44000:rwx media` on. The directory is exported with `rw,sync,no_subtree_check`.

On my client, I can run `nfs4_getfacl media` and it returns the expected `A:g:44000:rwaDxtcy` line.

Permissions on `media` are `drwxrwxr-x`

If I run `mkdir media/foo` on the client I get `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/share/media/foo’: Permission denied`

I have verified that:

- My client user belongs to a group with gid `44000` (`$ id -> ...44000(media-write)`)
- ACLs function as expected server side mounted locally
- The `acl` option is present in the fstab mounting line for the share (this shouldn't be necessary but I added it just in case)
- `umask` is `0002` on client and server

Answer (score 1):

In order for secondary groups to work over NFS, assuming the `--manage-gids` flag is on, you must have a matching user on the host with the same secondary group assignment. In this case my UID on the server did *not* have the `media-write` secondary. In fact, a user with the matching ID did not even exist. In this case, the two possible fixes would be to add a matching user server-side and assign it the appropriate group, or to disable the `--manage-gids` flag and ensure you don't violate the 16 group limit for NFS.

This applies to both regular group ownership permissions and ACLs.